# Display IFrame from same domain under SSL

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, iframe

I am trying to wrap a login section of our page in an iframe which has been created with SSL and display it on several pages across our companies website (kind of like a login widget).

However I keep getting an error on the page rendering the iframe indicating that:

> Refused to display  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

The login widget and webpages that I want to display it on are hosted under the same domain, is this an issue?

I have searched around and nothing seems to be able to avoid this problem. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts" src="https://<sitename>/loginiframewidget.aspx"></iframe>
```

At the moment these are what I have in my web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="access-control-allow-headers" value="content-type" />
    <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />-->
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' mysite.com.au"/>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOWALL"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

And the headers that appear in Chrome Dev Tools on the page are:

[image]

Comment: Which http headers have you?, specifically x-frame-options and Content-Security-Policy header,

Comment: Are the webpages that display the iframe using SSL? http//<sitename> and https//<sitename> would be considered different origins.

Comment: @EdwardPescetto that is an excellent point, the site appears to work when I disable SSL so this seems the likely cause, is there a way for my iframe to accept the url from a different origin but only one I specifically define?

Comment: If your login page is on SSL, then your only option is to put the other webpages on SSL as well, if you want them to hold the iframe.

Comment: @JanBluemink Added details to the question for headers

Comment: It's strange that the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` is being sent. Can you check IIS/configs/code to ensure that is not being set somewhere? I haven't been able to replicate this by default.

Comment: @jammykam I have tried searching through the code to see if SAMEORIGIN is being set somewhere and I was unable to location anything, I think I read somewhere that .NET or Chrome automatically sets this...

Comment: @MatthewPigram It won't be Chrome, since it appears in your Response Headers it must be something server side. I tried with a self signed cert locally, and by default IIS is not sending that header. But, it is self signed and so may not be acting in the same way. It may also vary on Windows Server vs local dev :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are security issues with this implementation anyway.

The first is that you can't be sure the content of the unencrypted page hasn't been altered on transmission and has pointed the src of the iframe elsewhere.

The second is that even if a user logs in with SSL, their session ID in the cookie is being sent in the clear and is easy to spoof.

Would you consider running the entire site in SSL? These days servers cope with this better than you'd think, and you wouldn't need iframes any more.

Comment: I want to run the site in SSL, however the client does not even after explaining how the performance impact will be minimal :S. Unfortunately I have no choice. I have come across this http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls which seems to suggest a possible javascript workaround but I am not sure how I might implement it in the most secure way.

Comment: Mixed mode is generally a bad idea, beware of the ramifications: http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/04/5-ways-to-implement-https-in.html?m=1 and http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/03/c-is-for-cookie-h-is-for-hacker.html?m=1

Comment: @jammykam this does not help me implement a HTTPS secured IFrame on a HTTP site, I fully understand the ramifications of doing this, but as mentioned before I have no choice. If everything goes to hell I can just blame the client for not listening to my warnings. At any rate I need to implement HTTPS IFrame on a HTTP page

Comment: My pitch would be "the alert that 'some of the content on this page is not secured' would send me, as a user, running". If they won't listen to reason and run the entire site as SSL, they are begging for their users to be confronted with a scary security warning each time the enter the site.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-ancestors) directive of the [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy) header, and the [X-Frame-Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header for older versions of IE.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy

You can add these through IIS, or add them into your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...    
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' mywebsite.com" />
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM http://mywebsite.com" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>    
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

The headers should now be sent down to the browser:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction, however I am getting an error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`. I am using X-Frame-Options : ALLOWALL as ALLOW-FROM as far as I am aware is not compatible with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Also this `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "<http site>" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.` This is from javascript that attempts to unhide the iframe control

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` doesn't work in Chrome/Firefox so you need to send down `Content-Security-Policy` for those browsers instead. For the javascript, you could try setting `document.domain`: http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls

Comment: I already had the Content-Security-Policy set up as in your example. Should it be something like `frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.com or http://example.com or just example.com`

Comment: I tried locally exactly as I noted, BUT I tried it cross domain with different urls since I didn't have SSL setup. I'll try self cert'ing to try to replicate (but really not my area of expertise...)

Answer (score 1):

No means big No, you just can't do it, you can't access SSL resources on non SSL page, and is your client willing to expose everything on internet? Allowing frame options will still not work because browser will not allow you to cross SSL boundaries.

HTTP is not at all secure, this is the reason, every site in google is now under SSL, because non SSL content can be altered by ISPs and Firewalls, in fact ISPs, Firewalls and other routers are continuously injecting scripts on page to monitor traffic.

Explain your client that today running an authenticated session under non HTTPS is equivalent to locking doors of home but leaving all windows open !!!.

With keep alive, SSL negotiation any way happens only once and performance is very negligible, you can improve site speed by outsourcing CDN to CloudFront or any other CDN with their subdomain SSL.

**OAuth - But Recommended only under SSL anyway**

You can implement your own OAuth Provider and use it to distribute OAuth tokens that can be used to validate in your website at server side. Your site can use secondary tokens issued by OAuth provider to validate user and you can redirect users to OAuth Provider which can run under SSL. This way, you can allow users to do limited non secure things under authentication on non SSL pages. Just like how you can use Facebook/Google login etc under non SSL sites as well.